# How can I ignore specific TODOs in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is marking certain Spanish translation files and blocks of text as being TODOs (Not all of them, but definitely "all of them". heh.) How can I:

1) ignore specific incorrectly highlighted "todo" items

2) if that's not possible, exclude certain types of files (my translation files) from the TODO panel

Comment: Try clicking on the "Scope based" tab and see if you can create a scope that excludes your localization files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Scope Based` feature of the `TODO` view to exclude classes or packages from the reported TODOs. To engage this feature click on the `Scope Based` tab in the [`TODO`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/todo-tool-window.html) view and then click on the `...` button next to the [`Scope`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scopes.html) dropdown. In the resulting dialog you can define inclusion and exclusion patterns to isolate the classes (though not code blocks within a class) which you wish to ignore.

**Example**

Given this class:

```
package org.glytching.sandbox.translation;

public class Foo {

    // TODO i would like to ignore this TODO
    private static String something;
}
```

And this class:

```
package org.glytching.sandbox;

public class Bar {

    // TODO i would not like to ignore this TODO
    private static String something;
}
```

Here's a screenshot showing the scope based definition required to ignore the package which contains the class: `Foo`:

[image]

And here's a screenshot showing the resulting TODO view:

[image]